# Notificações Android não são lançadas

Tags: android, android-notification, notificação

Utilizo o RTP_WAKEUP para "acordar" o meu dispositivo quando este se dá conta que tem notificações a lançar e de facto consigo lançar notificações para daqui a 10/15 ou ate 20 minutos, mas quando tento lançar uma notificação daqui a 2 horas ou ate dias esta não ocorre...

Deixo aqui parte do código onde elaboro todo o processo. 
O que tenho de errado para isto acontecer?

Classe onde crio o alarme, para lançar a notificação.

```
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 07);

            // Obtém um alarm manager
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(getContext().ALARM_SERVICE);

            // O id a ser usado no pending intent
            int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

            // Prepare the intent which should be launched at the date
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), CriarNotificacao.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);

            // Obtém o pending intent
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            // Regista o alerta no sistema.
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 07);

            // Obtém um alarm manager
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(getContext().ALARM_SERVICE);

            // O id a ser usado no pending intent
            int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

            // Prepare the intent which should be launched at the date
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), CriarNotificacao.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);

            // Obtém o pending intent
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            // Regista o alerta no sistema.
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Classe onde lanço a notificação

```
  public class CriarNotificacao extends BroadcastReceiver {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                int id = extras.getInt("id");

                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                                0,
                                intent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                        );

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setContentTitle("titulo")
                        .setContentText("mensagem")
                        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);
                mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_cake);

                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(id));

                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vibrator.vibrate(1500);

                mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
            }
        }
```

Comment: O problema é o dispositivo não "acordar", só "acordar" quando o período é pequeno(10/15 ou ate 20 minutos) ou nada tem haver com o "acordar", mas sim por o período ser longo(2 horas ou até dias)?

Comment: @ramaral quanto o tempo excedeum tempo mais largo, ou seja quando tento agendar uma notificação para daqui por exemplo +40 minutos ele simplesmente não faz nada, a notificação não aparece

Comment: @ramaral e quando volto a abrir a app a notificação (aquele que agendei para os +40 minutos) que não foi mostrada aparece...apesar de o horario que deveria ter aparecido já expirou

Comment: o mais estranho é que já coloquei um intervalo relativamente grande uns 20 minutos, e a aplicação mesmo não estando aberta a notificação apareceu no horario previsto, à bem pouco tempo testei para os 40 minutos e nada aconteceu....

Comment: O que eu quero que esclareça é se isso tem haver com o dispositivo estar "acordado" ou não.

Comment: @ramaral penso que sim...

Comment: eu acho que o telemovel so acorda quando o tempo é relativamente "pequeno"

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de um BroadcastReceiver use um IntentService para lançar a notificação.

```
public class CriarNotificacao extends IntentService {

    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    public CriarNotificacao() {
        super("name");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "BootService");
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

        //Lance a notificação aqui.
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    if(wakeLock.isHeld()){
        //Verificou-se que o iluminar do ecrã
        //não acontecia devido ao WakeLock ser
        //rapidamente libertado(apesar de PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE !?).
        try {
            //Atrasa a libertação do WakeLock
            //de forma a permitir a iluminação do ecrâ.
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            wakeLock.release();
        }

    }
}
```

O serviço usa o PowerManager para adquirir um WakeLock para permitir que a notificação seja lançada.

Tem de alterar a forma como obtém o PendingIntent, usando `getService()` em vez de `getBroadcast()`:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getContext(), id, intent,
                                                       PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Adicione a permissão

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
```

ao *AndroidManifest.xml*

Comment: antes de mais quero agradecer toda a sua disponibilidade em tentar me ajudar.

Comment: Antes de testar aquilo que me sugeriu,o IntentService, eu testei novamente com o código que tinha. Agendei 2 notificações, em sitios distintos mas que usam a mesma classe "CriarNotificacao", aproximadamente às 09:30h agendei uma para as 10:05h e outra para as 10:02h, o mais estranho e que me esta a preocupar é que a das 10:02h não apareceu no horario devido, e a das 10:05h apareceu no horario certo.O mais caricato de tudo, na minha opinião, é que a notificação que devia ter aparecido às 10:02h apareceu logo depois da notificação das 10:05h  @ramaral

Comment: Esse comportamento é possível para apps com targetSdkVersion >= 19. Se quer que o alarme seja "exacto", em vez de `alarmManager.set()`, use `alarmManager.setExact()`.